# Which years to write into copyright header?

Tags: copyright-display

How should I write the years in the copyright header?

Just `firstyear`, every year like `firstyear, ..., currentyear`, the range `firstyear-currentyear` or just the last `currentyear`?

For example, I currently work on code I wrote in 2011, and it just says `Copyright 2011` in the header.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question; it's more of a legal question, and IMO is off-topic here. It's at least "not constructive", because non-attorneys here will offer several different opinions that will generate discussions, and selecting a single "correct" answer isn't really possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that you should write the year (or the range of years) that you developed the code in. Copyrights expire after some time, the value you enter is used to determine that time.

Updated:

There is some nice information on this subject on Wikipedia here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright.

> Typically, the duration of copyright is the whole life of the creator plus fifty to a hundred years from the creator's death, or a finite period for anonymous or corporate creations. Some jurisdictions have required formalities to establishing copyright, but most recognize copyright in any completed work, without formal registration.
>
> "Copyright", followed by the year of the first publication of the work and the name of the copyright holder. Several years may be noted if the work has gone through substantial revisions.

Comment: so start of developping to last changed? e.g. `2021-2023`

Answer (score 4):

I think the dates should reflect the year(s) the content was [worked](http://blog.case.edu/webdev/2007/01/03/copyright.html) on, however some shops want the compile date in your source code comments.